# Django static files not showing

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I hav gone through my settings.py file to look at my static file setting

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

but all my static files are nt showing when the page loads.
Please what could be going on

---

The static files where formerly working I do not know what i did that altered everything and I have gone through my settings file but found nothing wrong and the files are intact, it has not been changed

Answer (score 0):

just remember to write at the top of the page

```
{% load static %}
```

Comment: I have already done that earlier but I do not know why it is not showing. The static files where formerly working I do not know what i did that altered everything

Answer (score 0):

There are are more than one static_root, possibly remove the static_root it looks same thing to static_dir